# Null reference Exception after default constructor

Tags: c#, thread-safety, visual-studio-2017

I've met a very weird (for me..) Exception. It happens only rarely, but does...

My class isn't static, but has only one static attribute:

```
static Dictionary<string, ManualResetEvent> resetEvents = 
    new Dictionary<string, ManualResetEvent>();
```

When I'm trying to add for the first time a reset event - I'm getting, sometimes, a Null Reference Exception. Might this be related to two different Threads trying to add instance?

```
static ManualResetEvent resetEventsGet(string key)
{
    if (resetEvents.ContainsKey(key))
        return resetEvents[key];
    ManualResetEvent reste = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    resetEvents.Add(key, reste); //System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' HOW???
    return reste;
}
```

When I'm looking in the "watch" or immediate window there's no null anywhere (the dictionary or the resetEvent).

p.s - I tagged it for visual studio 2017 because it never happened to me before, although code didn't change.
Any idea? Thanks

Comment: That is weird, since it seem tot get past the `ContainsKey` call.  You don't have `resetEvents = null` anywhere do you?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me. Why the exception isn't thrown in the line `if (resetEvents.ContainsKey(key))`? Are you sure you are not making that field `null` from any where else in the code?

Comment: What does the call to `new ManualResetEvent(false)` do? It does not make the field `null`?

Comment: "When I'm trying to add for the first time a reset event" - that sounds like you can reproduce this. So please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is not thread-safe.  If you access it from multiple threads without using locks, you can get odd results including an NRE

Comment: Totally sure. Checked ten times...and now again, the dictionary has only three references - all in front of you (declaration, containsKey and add)

Comment: @Joe I mentioned such an option in the question, but can't understand how this may happen. Could you please explain more? Thanks

Comment: @UweKeim not all questions that contain words NullReferenceException are duplicates of that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's perfectly possible if you call `resetEventsGet` from multiple threads. `Dictionary.Add` is not thread safe, and when you call it from multiple threads - weird things might happen, which includes throwing 'NullReferenceException'. It's relatively easy to reproduce with the following code:

```
class Program {
    static Dictionary<string, ManualResetEvent> resetEvents = new Dictionary<string, ManualResetEvent>();

    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                resetEvents.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), new ManualResetEvent(false));
            })
            {
                IsBackground = true
            }.Start();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }      
}
```

This code not always, but very often, throws null reference exception inside `Dictionary.Insert` private method.

This happens because dictionary stores your values in array-like internal structures, and those structures are not of fixed size. When you add more values - dictionary might resize it's internal structures, and that resize might happen when another thread already enumerates them at the same time. Doing resize and enumeration at the same time might lead to many bad things, including null reference or index out of range exceptions.

So just don't ever do it and use proper locking. Or use collections that are designed for multithreaded access, like `ConcurrentDictionary<string, ManualResetEvent>`.

Comment: Thanks! finally managed to test - Actually I didn't have any exceptions on visual studio 2008 (framWork 3.5). on 2017 I had very few (after initiating array of Guid prior loop) , aside to some keyValues which just didn't enter (tried to fill with 1000 and found only 998...without any exception). Intresting. Thanks again. Obviously I add lock\ConcurrentDictionary now.

Comment: Ha!! finally it happened to me also in VS 2008... I think the actual difference was I never run VS 2008 on release mode, but 2017 I do... Now it happend on 2008 on release mode.

Answer (score 3):

If you are accessing this with multiple threads, you'd better lock it. The problem is, that the Dictionary isn't threadsafe. In this case, you can use the Dictionary itself as lockobject. *(because it is private)*

*Something like:*

```
static ManualResetEvent resetEventsGet(string key)
{
    lock(resetEvents)
    {
        ManualResetEvent result;

        // lookup the key
        if(!resetEvents.TryGetValue(key, out result))
            // if it doesn't exists, create a new one.
            resetEvents.Add(key, result = new ManualResetEvent(false));

        return result;
    }
}
```

Also `TryGetValue` is great. It is giving you the value and if it was present. *(so only one lookup instead of two)*